# cut a text between / / symbols

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed, find, cut

***i have some below strings***

- 2-0  854 0/413/5963  W   65.19   0   0   0.0 4.76    115.86
  ::1 www.example.com GET /server-status HTTP/1.1
- 2-0  854 0/413/5963  W       65.19   0   0   0.0 4.76    115.86
  ::1 www.example.com GET /server-status HTTP/1.1

***and i want output as below:-***

- server-status HTTP
- server-status HTTP

Comment: in the given sample input, is it two lines or four lines? if it is two, a simple `cut -d/ -f4 inputfile.txt` will do

Answer (score 2):

try

**awk**

```
.... | awk -F/ '{print $4}'
```

where

- `-F/` use / as sepaator
- `print $4` fourth field

**grep**

```
grep -o "[^/]*HTTP"
```

where

- `-o` only matched string
- `[^/]*HTTP` any char not a `/` followed by HTTP

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
awk -F/ '/GET/{print $2}' input.txt
```